# Osmolarity and osmotic pressure

Tags: biochemistry, concentration, pressure, osmosis

> You have discovered a new strain of bacteria called *Tankeromyces subtilis* that has a special outer membrane that is capable of withstanding high levels of osmotic pressure. These bacteria can survive osmotic pressure as high $\pu{1.3 kJ L-1}$, but not higher. The $(iC)_\mathrm{total}$ value for the inside of these bacteria is $\pu{630 mM}$.
>
> What is the lowest concentration of $\ce{NaCl}$ (in otherwise pure water) in which these bacteria can survive without bursting due to osmotic pressure?
>
> $R = \pu{8.3153 J mol-1 K-1}$ and $T = \pu{296 K}$.

The answer is $\pu{0.10 M}$, but I have no idea how to drive at that answer. However, I do know that it involves this equation:

$$p = iCRT$$

Comment: The units of osmotic pressure given may be confusing you.  kJ/L is a pressure unit becaues a Joule is equal to a Pascal-cubic meter.  $\textrm{J}=\textrm{Pa} \cdot \textrm{m}^3$  Does that give you enough to get started?

Comment: Ohhh. I didn't even think of it that way. Yes that was very helpful in getting started.

Answer (score 1):

The highest pressure they can handle is $\pu{1.3 kJ L-1}$, or $\pu{13000 J L-1}$. [In the formula](http://www.chem.purdue.edu/gchelp/howtosolveit/Solutions/osmoticpressure.html) you use the ideal gas constant $0.08206$ and the temperature given to find the concentration the maximum pressure it can handle.

This comes out at $\pu{0.53 M}$ or $\pu{530 mM}$ and that's the maximum concentration it can handle. To find the minimum, you subtract $530$ from $630$ giving you $\pu{100 mM}$ or $\pu{0.1 M}$, which is the lowest concentration it can handle.

Comment: I find this rather confusing to follow; probably you should've included the formula for osmotic pressure and why exactly you stick with these units.